# What are the possible reasons why Knn works much better than SVM?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, k-nearest-neighbour

So, I have my training data and my test data and the problem is that using KNN it works very good (in fact works almost perfectly) but using SVM or some CART Models works very bad.

So, I'd like to know some possible reasons why this is happening. I think that the code that I'm using it is well implemented.

This is a problem of classification for more than $2$ classes.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of other things you need to clarify for your question to be answered. kNN and SVM both have different learning methods. Some questions you will need to clarify further are:
What kernel are you using for SVM?
Did you tune the hyperparameters for SVM using grid search etc?
Are you measuring the metric on the the training set itself?
What k did you take for kNN?
What is the dimensionality of your data?
Number of training points?

Knn performing almost perfectly can happen by choosing k=1 and calculating the error metric on the train set itself

Maybe if you clarify these things there will be a more clearer picture of the situation.